# Collect results from parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a piece of code like this:

```
List<Egg> eggs = hens.parallelStream().map(hen -> {
    ArrayList<Egg> eggs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (hen.hasEgg()) {
        eggs.add(hen.getEgg());
    }
    return eggs;
}).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But in this way I have to create an ArrayList for every hen, and eggs are not collected until a hen is 100% processed. I would like something like this:

```
List<Egg> eggs = hens.parallelStream().map(hen -> {
    while (hen.hasEgg()) {
        yield return hen.getEgg();
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But Java does not have yield return. Is there a way to implement it?

Comment: You should add your `Hen` class definition. Also, what specifically are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a partial result to be available (as in a partially populated `List<Egg>`) that you can start processing while collection of eggs continues? Or are you simply trying to collect all eggs from all hens and the fact that processing must complete on all hens before you have a collection is not a problem?

Comment: In this case I am just collecting all eggs. But it will be good to see what we can do if we have .processEggs() instead of .collect() in the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Hen` class is poorly adapted to the Stream API. Provided that you cannot change it and it has no other useful methods (like `Collection<Egg> getAllEggs()` or `Iterator<Egg> eggIterator()`), you can create an egg stream like this:

```
public static Stream<Egg> eggs(Hen hen) {
    Iterator<Egg> it = new Iterator<Egg>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return hen.hasEgg();
        }

        @Override
        public Egg next() {
            return hen.getEgg();
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, 0), false);
}
```

Now you can use it in the following manner:

```
List<Egg> eggs = hens.parallelStream()
                     .flatMap(hen -> eggs(hen))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course better `Stream` implementation might be possible if you can change the `Hen` class.

Comment: getEgg() is complex and I need to think how to change it. But if we have a getAllEggs() for Hen, isn't it the same as my current implementation where you have to create an arraylist to collect all eggs for a hen?

Comment: Hen is like Iterator; one can easily create an Iterator<Egg> from a Hen.  Then use Spliterator.spliteratorUnknownSize to turn that into a Spliterator, use StreamSupport.to turn that into a stream(), and flatMap it.

Comment: @user2316040 The usual problem with iterator-like constructs -- in this case hasEgg/getEgg -- is that the checking logic and the getting logic overlap and so they may have to share state in an uncomfortable way. You might consider creating a stream via Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator. This requires you only to override tryAdvance(), which fuses the checking and returning actions into a single method.

Comment: The irony is that `Spliterator`s created this way attempt to provide parallel support by, guess what, buffering values into an array upon splitting, so all the work trying to provide a lazy fetching goes away at this point.

Comment: @Holger A spliterator created from an iterator has the same issue of batching for parallel support. What I was addressing was the ease with which someone could bring up a stream. If you have an iterator handy, great. If not, hasNext() might have to do a bunch of work and cache the result, and next() has to check and invalidate the cache, etc. With spliterator.tryAdvance() this can all be done in one method, so it might be more convenient to write.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I already said at other places that I prefer implementing `Spliterator` over implementing `Iterator` as well. My comment was referring to the answer’s way of creating a `Spliterator`, comparing it with the original approach of simply adding to an `ArrayList`. But the same applies to a custom subclass of `AbstractSpliterator` as well. That’s why I said in my answer that this work does't pay off.

Answer (score 2):

The iteration logic using `hasEgg()` and `getEgg()` is *stateful* as these method’s results depend on the previous invocations. Therefore, processing a single `Hen` can’t be parallelized unless you manage to change the interface completely.

That said, your worrying about the `ArrayList` is unnecessary. When the stream implementation executes the `collect` operation in parallel, it has to buffer the values for each thread anyway and combine these buffers afterwards. It might even be the case that the operation doesn’t benefit from parallel execution at all.

What you can do, is to replace the `ArrayList` by a `Stream.Builder` as it’s optimized for the use case of only adding until constructing the `Stream`:

```
List<Egg> eggs = hens.parallelStream().flatMap(hen -> {
    Stream.Builder<Egg> eggStream = Stream.builder();
    while(hen.hasEgg()) {
        eggStream.add(hen.getEgg());
    }
    return eggStream.build();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So far this gives me the best performance. However I accepted the other one because that one also works for the case when .processEggs() is used in the end instead of .collect().

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the existence of a `getEggs()` method, you can use the following to collect all of the eggs.

```
List<Egg> eggs = hens.parallelStream()
    .filter(Hen::hasEggs)
    .map(Hen::getEggs)
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);
```

The code assumes that `getEggs()` returns a `Collection`. You could eliminate the `filter(Hen::hasEggs)` if `getEggs()` returns an empty `Collection` when the `Hen` has no `Eggs`.

Comment: Why do you think `.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);` is better than `.collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: I did some test and it seems .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll) is not as fast as .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: The problem is that you need to collect all eggs. If you simply use `Collectors.toList()`, you would be collecting a `List<Collection<Egg>>`. By using `.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll)` you can combine all of the `Collection<Egg>` returned by `getEggs()` into a single `List<Egg>`.

Comment: @StuartMarks this answer was in response to the discussion surrounding whether you could collect all `Eggs` if `Hen` had a `getEggs()` method. In the absence of a definition of the `Hen` class (which I had requested but is apparently unavailable), and in the absence of a declaration that `Hen` does not have a `getEggs()` method, I felt that it was not unreasonable to assume the existence of `getEggs()` .

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Sure, that's a reasonable assumption, I was just making a little joke.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 I meant .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()) was faster than .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll) in my test.